# Авторизация через Telegram. Несколько виджетов на 1-й странице

Tags: javascript, html, авторизация, telegram

С самой авторизацией проблем нет. А вот с размещением нескольких виджетов авторизации на 1-й страниц - есть.

```css
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
   <div class="wrap">TestSite   
    <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?4" data-telegram-login="TestRobot" data-size="medium" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
   </div>

    <div class="wrap">TestSite 2  
    <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?4" data-telegram-login="TestRobot" data-size="medium" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
   </div>
```

Как видите, скрипт отработал только в 1 месте. Как установить виджет в разных местах страницы? 
Ссылка на виджет - https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login

Comment: ты же понимаешь, что просто подключил библиотеку виджета дважды?

Comment: @norbornen, понимаю) Но она отрабатывает единожды) Возможно есть какие-то настройки либо ухищрения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумал вот такой костыль: Отслеживаю изменения DOM-дерева в целевом объекте (там добавляется iframe). Клонирую этот iframe и вставляю в любое место страницы

```js
const target = document.getElementById('one');
const mutationConfig = {
 childList: true,
 subtree: true,
 characterData: true,
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
   const elem = mutations[0].addedNodes[0]
   appendTG(elem)
});
observer.observe(target, mutationConfig)

function appendTG(elem){
const clone = elem.cloneNode(true)
const next = document.getElementById('two');
next.appendChild(clone)
}
```

```css
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
   <div id="one" class="wrap">Test  
    <script defer src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?4" data-telegram-login="TestBot" data-size="medium" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
   </div>
    <div id="two" class="wrap">Test 2  

   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Трохи інша ситуація: віджет на сторінці + виклик віджета в модальному вікні.

Вирішено шляхом зміни id у <iframe id="telegram-login-my_bot" ...> під час виклику вікна:

```
$('#telegram-login-my_bot').attr('id', 'telegram-login-my_bot-');
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык